# How to set value of html input date tag from code behind

Tags: c#, html, date, webforms

I have an ASP.NET C# web forms project with an input date tag as shown below

```
<input type="date" id="dtpCustomerSince" runat="server" name="dtpCustomerSince">
```

I am able to save date in dd/mm/yyyy as DateTime and am able to retrieve data from AS400 into datatable and using this line to set date during retrieval

```
 dtpCustomerSince.Value =pdtCustomer.Rows[0]["WCCSDT"].ToString().Split().First();
```

However the date is not being set in HTML control

when i debug and check the value is

```
dtpCustomerSince.Value ="16/08/2019"
```

Answer (score 0):

The date has to be set in yyyy-MM-dd format from code behind .I used the code below and it works fine

```
                    string[] convertdate;
                    lscustomersince= pdtCustomer.Rows[0]["WCCSDT"].ToString().Split().First();
                    convertdate = lscustomersince.Split('/');
                    dtpCustomerSince.Value = convertdate[2] + "-" + convertdate[1] + "-" + convertdate[0];
```